# If the tangent at point $P_1$ on curve $ax^3-y+b=0$ meets the curve again at $P_2$. The tangent at $P_2$ meets at $P_3$ and so on. Find $a$ and $b$?

Tags: calculus

Here, I assumed a point $P_1 (x_1,y_1)$ and wrote equation of tangent at point $P_1$. Then made it pass through $P_2$. After some simplification I got

$x_2=-2x_1$,

$x_3=4x_1$,

$x_4=-8x_1$.

I see the abscissas are in GP.
But how am I supposed to find $a$ and $b$?

The options are given as

A. $1$, $0$

B. $2$, $7$

C. $3$, $5$

D. $4$, $9$

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.- A true puzzle. I chose the most "favorable" graph and indeed, my intuition did not fail me. The answer is the cubic $3x^3-y+5=0$ i.e. $C=(3,5)$.

In fact, choosing $P_1=(0.693,5.998)$ we get $P_2=(-1.386,-2.988)$, then $P_3=(2.772,68.899)$ and finally $P_4=(-5.544,-506.201)$ according with the statement of the problem.

In the attached figure the red points $P_1$ and $P_2$. Points $P_3$ and $P_4$ go off the chart.
[image]